# Python ctypes - how to use prototype on a function in a structure

Tags: python, function-pointers, ctypes

ctypes allows creating a structure where the fields can themselves be pointers to functions. I have that part successfully working. However, I cannot figure out how to set the "paramflags" for a function in a structure. I can only set it for those functions directly defined by the DLL.

Example...this code example is something that is seems to work well for me, and takes advantage of a lot of good ctypes features:

```
# rough ctypes code for specify the IN/OUT paramters for a funct that does work
MyDLL = CDLL(dllpath)

# first parameter is return code, the second I want to be an OUT
prototype = CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_uint,POINTER(ctypes.c_uint))

# following documentation, I turn my parameter in to an OUT
paramflags = ( (2,) ) 
MyFunc = prototype("MyFunc",MyDLL)

# another nice feature after prototype has be called/created,
# we can specify error check
MyFunc.errcheck = MyErrorCheck 

# at this point, MyFunc can return my OUT parameter.
value = MyFunc()
```

My question is:

How do I get these same features (paramflags and errcheck) if I have to define my function as a member of a structure?

I can set the attribute to be CFUNCTYPE, but since I can not do the actual creation, I don't understand how to set the paramflags or the errcheck in the struct definition.

```
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("MyFunc", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_uint,POINTER(ctypes.c_uint))) ]

MyDLL = CDLL(dllpath)
ptr = MyDLL.FunctionReturnsPtr()
Foo = cast(ptr,POINTER(MyStruct))

# if i could figure out how to set the paramflags, 
# then I would now be able to do:
value = Foo.MyFunc()
```

Comment: After looking further in to _ctypes.c code it appears this is not possible. The internal "paramflags" list is not exposed to Python. I can not determine what constructor is used to actually create the function, but the only way I could re-create is likely using the one that takes only address...that constructor does not take the paramflags argument....so I do not think this is possible